# Классификатор текста по стилю речи

Tags: текст, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, классификация

Здравствуйте. Стоит задача разработки классификатора текста по стилю речи (художественный, публицистический и т.д.). Необходимо сделать это на основе нейронной сети. Не могу определить характеристики, определяющие стиль текста и разобраться с тем, каким образом перевести исходный текст в вектор характеристик, с которыми и будет в итоге работать классификатор.

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, именно в этом и состоит задача нейронной сети, алгоритм будет выработан в процессе её обучения. Вы с нейронными сетями раньше работали?

Comment: @Кнопкатык Нет, очень поверхностно понимаю принципы устройства нейронных сетей. Каким ресурсом вы можете посоветовать воспользоваться, чтобы расставить все на свои места?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот таблица: [image: стили текстов]
(Картинка таблицы взята [отсюда](https://infourok.ru/konspekt-uroka-po-russkomu-yaziku-na-temu-stili-rechi-klass-265374.html))

Как видно из неё, в текстах разных стилей могут преобладать либо термины, либо описания, либо обращения, либо сленг либо иные Классы слов. Классы слов определит нейросетка после обучения. Стили она же будет определять, распознавая преобладание некооторого класса или сочетания классов слов в предоставляемом на распознание тексте. Структура текста так же будет среди признаков (хотя бы на уровне структурировано/не структурировано).
А дальше - литература про обучение нейросетки с подкреплением и обучение с учителем.

Самое главное - [Алгоритм обратного распространения ошибки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8). (https://habrahabr.ru/post/154369/ - на Хабре).

Comment: Вот тут - http://www.ampersant.ru/glaz/ - уклон в распознавание графических образов. Но принципы близки.

Comment: Научная работа, связанная с распознаванием классов http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/neyrosetevoe-raspoznavanie-klassov-v-rezhime-realnogo-vremeni (иногда, научные работы бывают полезны).

Comment: благодарю вас! Думаю, это должно помочь!

Comment: Вот ближе к теме: http://works.doklad.ru/view/ghxkvheaI3s.html распознавание слов естественного языка.

Comment: И вот, думаю, пригодится: http://is.ifmo.ru/diploma-theses/28_07_2007_Sujasov_magistry.pdf Но это ближе к графическому анализу символов.